# running a flask app .py with python instead of "flask run"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i am trying to run my app.py which is in flask with `"python app.py"` instead of `"flask run"`. i have the following in the app.py. but when i run it via python, the html pages dont show up and says requested url not found. i am not sure what i am missing here.
keep in mind the app runs fine when i use `flask run` command. the webpage shows on the browser fine. but when i use the `"python app.py"` the browser says the url is not found. i am not sure if i need to redirect something or not

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
if __name__ == "__main__":    
 app.run(host="10.147.180.15", port="80", debug=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

any help will be greatly appreciate it

Comment: Your example (mostly) works for me (app needs to be defined before the decorator for app, but I assume you have that part working). Where are you seeing the error message, in the browser or in the logs from your application?

Comment: The error is in the browser

Comment: This question would benefit from a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `app` before initiating routes:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Edited: fixed indentation

Comment: i apologize i have copy/paste it wrong, i have edited the post with the correct code

Comment: yes it works :) thanks so much now i can deploy my iis ;) can you please explain what is the difference if the "`if statemenet` be at the top or at the end of the code?

Comment: Either way, it shouldn't cause any problem, i was responding to your initial post (before the update).  There, you had  `app = Flask(__name__)` after `app.run` and that's more like referencing a variable before its declaration.